# How can I use regex to grab the information on the END of a line?

Tags: php, regex

For example,

`http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19`

When visiting that URL, it will return:

```
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: Sugar Grove, IL
IP: 12.215.42.19
```

I want to set `Sugar Grove, IL` to a variable, after visiting that URL.

How would I make it find the City, and then set it to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<?php
$page = "Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: Sugar Grove, IL
IP: 12.215.42.19
";

preg_match( '/City:\s*([^\n]+)/', $page, $matches );

echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Comment: You can just use `.+`.  By default `.` doesn't match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x=<<<CODE
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: Sugar Grove, IL
IP: 12.215.42.19
CODE;

preg_replace('`\nCity:\s(.*)\r`Ue','$city="$1";',$code);
```

Of course, we are using eval() here, so only if you are 100% sure of data integrity